# JavaScript make AJAX content fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How would I make the content fade into the div with the id viewRoul every time the script runs to load new content?

```
function list_roul(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200){
            document.getElementById("viewRoul").innerHTML = hr.responseText;
        }
    }
    hr.open("GET", "listRoul.php?t=" + Math.random(), true);
    hr.send();
}
```

I tried using

```
$('#viewRoul').html(html).fadeIn()
```

but it didn't work!

Comment: this `$('#viewRoul').html(html).fadeIn()` needs jQuery

Comment: Do you get errors in the error console? How doesn't it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the content's already visible (which it would be by default), you'll need to hide it before it can fade in:

```
$('#viewRoul').html(html).hide().fadeIn();
```

**Example:**

```js
$('#b1').click(function () {
    $('#one').html($(this).data('text')).fadeIn();
});
$('#b2').click(function () {
    $('#two').html($(this).data('text')).hide().fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1" type="button" data-text="lorem ipsum">One</button>
<div id="one"></div>
<button id="b2" type="button" data-text="lorem ipsum">Two</button>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#MyDiv').hide().html(content).fadeIn({ duration: 2000 });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nYbHs/

You can adjust the speed by changing duration. Here is more documentation on fadeIn: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

**Clarification update:** This code needs to go in your ajax callback function.  The content would be either the response itself (if it's already in the HTML format you want) or the response parsed into a content string in the HTML format that you want.

Like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: yourUrl,
    type: 'get',
    data: yourData,
    async: true,
    success: function(response) 
    {
        $('#MyDiv').hide().html(response).fadeIn({ duration: 2000 });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The "viewRoul" element is visible, you need to hide it first.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ujCtJ/2/)

```
$('#viewRoul').hide().html(html).fadeIn('slow');
```

You can read more about jQuery ui here [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Answer (score 0):

Set your #viewroul div to display hidden, if it's supposed to be hidden initially.  And on Ajax success.  Just make #viewroul fade In.  or also #viewroul.show('slow');